# ¿ Como puedo asignarle un evento click a cada boton?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cada vez que el for itera la función `eliminarCorreo(id)` imprime el id pero no la referencia del botón, como no puedo obtener la referencia no he logrado asignarle un evento.

edit

La función traer correos me devuelve un json con contenido de correos.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("El Documento esta Listo.")
    function traerCorreos(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/json-correos",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                imprimirCorreos(data)
            },
        })
    }
```

La función `imprimirCorreos(data)` recorre la `data` que recibe que en resumen es un json con correos(id, nombre, contenido, etc), esta función pinta el correo en un div con párrafos y botones, los botones tienen el id del correo.

```
        function imprimirCorreos(data){
        var largoListaLlaves = data.llaves.length

        for(var i = 0; i < largoListaLlaves; i++){
            var llave = data.llaves[i]
            var objCorreo = data.todos_correos[llave]
            var llaveBtn = `${llave}${i}`

            document.getElementById("contenedor-correos").innerHTML += `
            <div class='correo' id='${llave}'>
                <h2>Emisor: ${objCorreo.nombre}</h2>
                <p><strong>Correo</strong>: ${objCorreo.correo}</p>
                <div class='botones-correos'>
                    <button id='${llaveBtn}' class='eliminar-correo btn-correos' onclick='${eliminarCorreo(llaveBtn)}'>Eliminar</button>
                    <button class='contestar-correo btn-correos'>Responder</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
        }
    }

    traerCorreos()
```

cada botón tiene el atributo `onclick` con la función `eliminarCorreo(id)`
que recibe el id del botón.

cada vez que recargo la pagina en consola imprimen los ids de los botones ya que en la función `eliminarCorreo` así la programe, pero cuando trato de obtener la referencia del boton mediante su id e imprimirlo en consola me muestra null y todavía no logro entender por que.

function eliminarCorreo(id){

```
  console.log(id)
  var btn = document.getElementById(`${id}`)
  console.log(btn)      
    }
})
```

la idea es que cada botón al ser presionado imprima si id y su referencia para luego poder realizar la lógica correspondiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Favor brindar más información, que es lo que estás haciendo, como es el html, que comportamiento esperas?, mientras más claro sea el planteo más sencillo podrá ser entender la idea y ayudarte.

Comment: @LuisS.Romero Ahí la edite espero que se entienda

Comment: Genial, lo estaba viendo, te animás a poner un ejemplo de la estructura del JSON? Con eso ya podemos ver donde está el problema

Comment: según yo el json me funciona bien ya que puedo sacar sus datos y poder manipularlos

Comment: El json está perfecto, hice unos cuantos cambios, espero sea lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto podría ayudarte, armé un objeto de prueba data similar a lo que recibís, así no tenés que cambiar mucho.

En html solo generé un div con el id contenedor-correos

En JavaScript puse lo siguiente, hice varios cambios, por las duda ve por línea.

```
const data = {
  llaves: ["m33443", "b3aad3", "v3dsaf", "y445gh"],
  todosCorreos: {
    m33443: { nombre: "Luis", correo: "aaa@algo.com" },
    b3aad3: { nombre: "Luis", correo: "bbb@algo.com" },
    v3dsaf: { nombre: "Luis", correo: "ddd@algo.com" },
    y445gh: { nombre: "Luis", correo: "eee@algo.com" },
  },
};

imprimirCorreos(data);

function imprimirCorreos(data) {
  //console.log(data.llaves.length)
  document.getElementById("contenedor-correos").innerHTML = "" //borro el contenedor, para que no re sepitan al borrar mails
  var largoListaLlaves = data.llaves.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < largoListaLlaves; i++) {
    //console.log(data.llaves[i])
    var llave = data.llaves[i];
    var objCorreo = data.todosCorreos[llave];
    var llaveBtn = `${llave}`;

    document.getElementById("contenedor-correos").innerHTML += `
            <div class='correo' id='${llave}'>
                <h2>Emisor: ${objCorreo.nombre}</h2>
                <p><strong>Correo</strong>: ${objCorreo.correo}</p>
                <div class='botones-correos'>
                    <button id='${llaveBtn}' class='eliminar-correo btn-correos' onclick='eliminarCorreo("${llaveBtn}")'>Eliminar</button>
                    <button class='contestar-correo btn-correos'>Responder</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            `;
  }
}

function eliminarCorreo(id) {
  console.log(id); // Verifico recibo ID
  const mailToDelete = data.llaves.indexOf(id); //Obtengo indice de ese id en el array
  data.llaves.splice(mailToDelete, 1); //Borro ese Id del array
  delete data.todosCorreos[id]; //Borro el objeto cuya propiedad era el id
  console.log(data); //Verifico que se elimine array y objeto
  imprimirCorreos(data) //Dibujo nuevamente la lista con data modificado
}
```

También agregué la funcionalidad de borrar correos del array y del objeto, y pongo en blanco el innerHTML antes de iniciar el for, para que cada vez que se dibuje la pantalla no repita los registos.

Solo te queda en el segundo botón asignar otra función y hacer lo que debas hacer al responder en este caso.

---

La otra opción es no llamar a las funciones desde html y hacer eventListeners, es un poco más complejo porque el tema es como identificar a cual escucha, en ese caso podrías hacer algo así:

```
const data = {
  llaves: ["m33443", "b3aad3", "v3dsaf", "y445gh"],
  todosCorreos: {
    m33443: { nombre: "Luis", correo: "aaa@algo.com" },
    b3aad3: { nombre: "Luis", correo: "bbb@algo.com" },
    v3dsaf: { nombre: "Luis", correo: "ddd@algo.com" },
    y445gh: { nombre: "Luis", correo: "eee@algo.com" },
  },
};

imprimirCorreos(data);

function imprimirCorreos(data) {
  //console.log(data.llaves.length)
  document.getElementById("contenedor-correos").innerHTML = ""; //borro el contenedor, para que no re sepitan al borrar mails
  var largoListaLlaves = data.llaves.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < largoListaLlaves; i++) {
    //console.log(data.llaves[i])
    var llave = data.llaves[i];
    var objCorreo = data.todosCorreos[llave];
    var llaveBtn = `${llave}`;

    document.getElementById("contenedor-correos").innerHTML += `
    <div class='correo' id='${llave}'>
    <h2>Emisor: ${objCorreo.nombre}</h2>
                <p><strong>Correo</strong>: ${objCorreo.correo}</p>
                <div class='botones-correos'>
                    <button id='${llaveBtn}' class='eliminar-correo btn-correos'>Eliminar</button>
                    <button class='contestar-correo btn-correos'>Responder</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    `;
  }
  let botonEliminar = document.querySelectorAll("button.eliminar-correo"); //Selecciono todos los botones con clase eliminar-correo
  for (const boton of botonEliminar) {
    boton.addEventListener("click", (event) => { // Los recorro y agrego un eventListener a cada uno
      console.log(event.target.id); // Verifico recibo ID
      const mailToDelete = data.llaves.indexOf(event.target.id);
      data.llaves.splice(mailToDelete, 1);
      delete data.todosCorreos[event.target.id];
      console.log(data); //Verifico que se elimine array y objeto
      imprimirCorreos(data); //Dibujo devuelta la lista
    });
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva, podés reemplazar mi data por tu respuesta ajax, lo dejarías tal cual lo tenés, solo borrás mi llamada a la función imprimirCorreos al principio, porque lo harías desde el success del ajax, quedo atento.

Comment: La segunda solución me sirvió perfecto y la adapte a jQuery.

Comment: Super!! Me alegro, quedo a las órdenes.